# ubuntu apache2 /var/www/html files permissions inconsistency for www-data

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php

here's my ll of /var/www/html

```
drwxr-x---  4 www-data www-data  4096 Jan 13 22:44 ./
drwxr-s---  3 www-data www-data  4096 Jan 11 17:16 ../
drwxr-x---  2 www-data www-data  4096 Jan 16 15:45 Directory1/
-rwxr-x---  1 www-data www-data 11321 Jan 11 17:16 index.html*
```

here's my ll of /var/www/html/Directory1

```
drwxr-x---  4 www-data www-data  4096 Jan 16 15:45 ./
drwxr-x---  4 www-data www-data  4096 Jan 13 22:44 ../
drwxr-x---  8 www-data www-data  4096 Jan 16 15:45 .git/
-rwxr-x---  1 www-data www-data  7351 Jan 16 15:45 my_file.php*
```

And, here's my ll of /var/www/html/Directory2

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4096 Jan 16 16:52 ./
drwxr-x--- 5 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 16 16:51 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       29 Jan 16 16:52 index.php
```

index.html and Directory2/index.php loads fine on the web browser but  /Directory1/my_file.php doesn't

Can someone throw some light as to why exactly this is happening? I tried all combinations of chmod. I just can't get the file to be executed on the browser.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Is there an error message from the web browser? Are you sure there is no errors in `/Directory1/my_file.php`?

Comment: my_file.php loads perfectly fine on my localhost without any issue. So, I cant figure out the problem